# Deploying Grails application on a large scale

Tags: grails, deployment, backend, frontend

I started looking into Grails and I felt quite comfortable writing a simple prototype web app with services, controllers, a RESTful interface and some simple views.

The usual way for deployment would be to package the web app into a .war (or .zip for plugins) and then deploy it to a application server e.g. Tomcat.

Assuming I will integrate the frontend into a larger existing frontend/portal, I don't want to package this together with some potentially heavy backend and put all this on the same application server, which was originally meant to host frontent/portal code only. Also the backend might provide services to be used by other applications.

Thinking about flexibilty in scalability, is there a possibility (or the need at all?) to seperateley deploy the frontend (views, maybe some controllers) and the backend (maybe the REST controllers?, services, domains) to different hosts, by packaging two separate modules? Anyone having experience rolling out a Grails app in large scale?